# Convert view from SQL Server to Redshift

Tags: sql-server, amazon-redshift, database-migration, sql-view

I have view in SQL Server, that I need to convert to Redshift

Here is the view:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.BE_ContactRelationsDual') AND type in (N'V'))
    DROP VIEW public.contactrelationsdual;
GO

CREATE VIEW public.contactrelationsdual
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT  CASE d.id
        WHEN 0 THEN
                cr.contactId
        ELSE
                cr.relatedContactId
        END me,
        CASE d.id
        WHEN 0 THEN
                cr.relatedContactId
        ELSE
                cr.contactId
        END him,
        cr.id, 
        cr.permissionId
FROM    public.contact_relations cr
CROSS JOIN
        public.system_dual d
WHERE   cr.contactId > 0
        AND cr.relatedContactId > 0
        AND cr.deletedDate IS NULL
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX
        UX_BE_ContactRelationsDual_Me_Him
ON      public.contactrelationsdual (me, him)
GO
```

I need to convert it to redshift. I have 2 problems:

This:

> ```
> CREATE VIEW public.contactrelationsdual
> WITH SCHEMABINDING
> ```

and this:

> ```
> IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id =
> OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.BE_ContactRelationsDual') AND type in (N'V'))     DROP
> VIEW public.contactrelationsdual; GO
> ```

How I can correctly convert it to Redshift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `with schemabinding`:

```
CREATE VIEW public.contactrelationsdual AS
SELECT (CASE d.id WHEN 0 THEN cr.contactId ELSE cr.relatedContactId
        END) as me,
       (CASE d.id WHEN 0 THEN cr.relatedContactId ELSE cr.contactId
        END) as  him,
        cr.id, 
        cr.permissionId
FROM public.contact_relations cr CROSS JOIN
     public.system_dual d
WHERE cr.contactId > 0 AND
      cr.relatedContactId > 0 AND
      cr.deletedDate IS NULL;
```

This is pretty standard SQL and should work on almost any database.

The `IF EXISTS` part can be replaced with:

```
drop view if exists public.contactrelationsdual;
```

There is no need for a clustered index in Redshift.

Comment: Okay, but also I have problem with clustered index. Seems redshift doesn;t has this syntax

Comment: And what about `IF EXISTS ` stuff

Comment: Yeah, I can drop view, but in sql it has subquery. Can I have it in redshift?

Comment: @EugeneSukh . . . This is all you need in Redshift.  There is no such thing as materialized views in that environment.